# Allow users to set up schedule for server-side scripts to run in Node

Tags: node.js, express, npm, cron, scheduled-tasks

I'm creating a project in Node & Express that allows users to schedule the server to run test scripts e.g. once every ten minutes. I looked into [node-schedule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule) which looks great however it seems that all scheduled tasks disappear if the server ever restarts Node.

[Cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron) looks good too but it has the problem that it doesn't seem to have a way to delete scheduled tasks after they have been set up.

If you were doing this, how would you go about it? I really don't want anything that's going to be complex, just need to schedule tasks, be able to delete individual tasks, and keep tasks in the event of a server reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution is to store the configurations for Cron in a database (since it takes a string as a parameter). Load the jobs from the db every time the app starts.

Comment: Is there a way to do this that doesn't rely on cron specifically? I'm developing on windows (though the server will ultimately be linux).

Comment: Cron does not use the system app `cron`; it's purely implemented in .js.

Comment: Oh! Didn't realise that. Neat.